# Count occurrences within a list of list of tuples

Tags: python, stream, counter

I think it is best to start with input and output:

```
list_of_items = [
    {"A": "abc", "B": "dre", "C": "ccp"},
    {"A": "qwe", "B": "dre", "C": "ccp"},
    {"A": "abc", "B": "dre", "C": "ccp"},
]

result = {'A-abc-->B': {'dre': 2},
          'A-abc-->C': {'ccp': 2},
          'A-qwe-->B': {'dre': 1},
          'A-qwe-->C': {'ccp': 1},
          'B-dre-->A': {'abc': 2, 'qwe': 1},
          'B-dre-->C': {'ccp': 3},
          'C-ccp-->A': {'abc': 2, 'qwe': 1},
          'C-ccp-->B': {'dre': 3}}
```

My initial input is items that come as a stream. Those items are basically dictionaries with key and value.
My goal is to get for each specific key and value the maximum value for all other keys that came with it.

So if out of 100 items, for the key "A" with value "1" I got in 90 items for key "B" the value "2" and in 10 items for key "B" the value "1111" I want to see a list that will show me those numbers. B2=90, B1111=10.

My code is working. 
But, my real life scenario contains more than 100000 different values for about 20 keys.
also, my final goal would be to run this as a job on Flink.

So I am looking for help with Counter / python stream api.

```
all_tuple_list_items = []
for dict_item in list_of_items:
    list_of_tuples = [(k, v) for (k, v) in dict_item.items()]
    all_tuple_list_items.append(list_of_tuples)

result_dict = {}
for list_of_tuples in all_tuple_list_items:
    for id_tuple in list_of_tuples:
        all_other_tuples = list_of_tuples.copy()
        all_other_tuples.remove(id_tuple)
        dict_of_specific_corresponding = {}

        for corresponding_other_tu in all_other_tuples:
            ids_connection_id = id_tuple[0] + "-" + str(id_tuple[1]) + "-->" + corresponding_other_tu[0]
            corresponding_id = str(corresponding_other_tu[1])

            if result_dict.get(ids_connection_id) is None:
                result_dict[ids_connection_id] = {corresponding_id: 1}
            else:
                if result_dict[ids_connection_id].get(corresponding_id) is None:
                    result_dict[ids_connection_id][corresponding_id] = 1
                else:
                    result_dict[ids_connection_id][corresponding_id] = result_dict[ids_connection_id][
                                                                           corresponding_id] + 1

pprint(result_dict)
```

Comment: I know my title is not exactly what I described. But (and that part of my problem) I do not know how to describe the task I am trying to do.. (hence going imperative and not declarative coding..)

Comment: Your data structure is very strange: a single dict in a list, numbers as strings.

Comment: numbers as strings are just some values for the keys. those can be letters or what ever.. you are right about the single dict. will fix.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you need. Explain better your example, which you posted.

Comment: editing now, got it to work but want a more elegant efficient faster solution.

Comment: I got the idea. Does it have something to do with graphs? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: not graphs... i have stream of events from different sensors. and i want to count the occurrences of "key:value"-"key:value" from all my different items. to decide which value for each key is the best "match" for another key and value... I know it is a bit mouth full..

Comment: You can check my answer and if you like it you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `permutations()` to generate all permutations of items in dicts and `Counter` to count them. Finally you can use `defaultdict()` to group items from `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import permutations
from pprint import pprint

list_of_items = [
    [{"A": "abc", "B": "dre", "C": "ccp"}],
    [{"A": "qwe", "B": "dre", "C": "ccp"}],
    [{"A": "abc", "B": "dre", "C": "ccp"}],
]

c = Counter(p for i in list_of_items       
              for p in permutations(i[0].items(), 2))
d = defaultdict(dict)
for ((i, j), (k, l)), num in c.items():
    d[f'{i}-{j}-->{k}'][l] = num

pprint(d)
```

#### Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'A-abc-->B': {'dre': 2},
             'A-abc-->C': {'ccp': 2},
             'A-qwe-->B': {'dre': 1},
             'A-qwe-->C': {'ccp': 1},
             'B-dre-->A': {'abc': 2, 'qwe': 1},
             'B-dre-->C': {'ccp': 3},
             'C-ccp-->A': {'abc': 2, 'qwe': 1},
             'C-ccp-->B': {'dre': 3}})
```

Comment: 1. is that solution considered fast and efficient (and hence scale able)? because you used existing libraries? 2. can you tell what is the equivalent libraries in java?
3. also, this code is good for my initial processing. but now I want to update my counters every day with new data. how is that done using counter and default dict?

Comment: answer for 3 is just use c.update with the new permutations from the new items :) (read the docs..)

Comment: 1. Yes, I don‘t think there is a better way to do it. Python libraries are very fast. 2. I don‘t know `Java`. 3. You can extend `list_of_items` with a new list `list_of_items.extend(new_list)‘ and run the script again. Or if you have really a lot of data you can use `pickle` to save you dict. Then you can load a dict and put a new list into `Counter`. When you load you dict you have to delete `d = defaultdict(dict)`. Otherwise it will overwrite your saved dict.

Comment: Yes you can do it also like that. But I would update your final dict (`defaultdict`) instead of `c`.

Comment: 4. permutations give A:B and also B:A how are we dealing with that?

Comment: Than you need combinations instead of permutations.

Comment: 3. what do you mean update default dict? i need to create a counter and recreate default dict - no?

Comment: combinations and permutations give same (correct) answer. I think default dict deals the same with A:B and B:A so it' s ok.

Comment: If you have other questions please put them on SO, so other can answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.
But, still wants to get a more efficient way.
Using counters and stream.
is that possible?

code

```
all_tuple_list_items = []
for dict_item in list_of_items:
    list_of_tuples = [(k, v) for (k, v) in dict_item[0].items()]
    all_tuple_list_items.append(list_of_tuples)

result_dict = {}
for list_of_tuples in all_tuple_list_items:
    for id_tuple in list_of_tuples:
        all_other_tuples = list_of_tuples.copy()
        all_other_tuples.remove(id_tuple)
        dict_of_specific_corresponding = {}

        for corresponding_other_tu in all_other_tuples:
            ids_connection_id = id_tuple[0] + "-" + str(id_tuple[1]) + "-->" + corresponding_other_tu[0]
            corresponding_id = str(corresponding_other_tu[1])

            if result_dict.get(ids_connection_id) is None:
                result_dict[ids_connection_id] = {corresponding_id: 1}
            else:
                if result_dict[ids_connection_id].get(corresponding_id) is None:
                    result_dict[ids_connection_id][corresponding_id] = 1
                else:
                    result_dict[ids_connection_id][corresponding_id] = result_dict[ids_connection_id][
                                                                           corresponding_id] + 1

pprint(result_dict)
```